# Can "fires" be used as the plural of "fire"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Can "fire" be plural? Can I say:

> Do fires cause cancer?

Comment: _Fires_ would seem to be house fires, building fires, and the like. You never know what's burning in a fire; for example, certain fire retardants have been shown to be carcinogenic when they burn, and ash itself contains carcinogens.

Comment: But it seems a bit terse to say _Fires cause cancer_ when what's actually meant seems to be _Inhaling smoke and fumes from burning material causes cancer._ That would include smoking tobacco, for instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the meanings of *fire* is a single conflagrative event. The word *fires* describes several such events. So, yes, *Do fires cause cancer?* is a grammatically conventional English sentence.

Comment: Would you agree that the said sentence is correct?

Comment: @lukas: I have edited my answer to say so.

Comment: Alternately, you could use _"Does fire cause cancer?"_ to refer to the concept of fire and I suspect that you'd get the same meaning unless you're specifically exploring the effects of experiencing multiple fires.

Comment: The use of the plural is extremely significant here, considering that the plural has a unique definition. The intention seems to be to state that such things as 'incidents of fire' (major fire), 'forest fires', etc., would cause cancer. Not any fire in general.

Comment: 'Fire' is a strange noun/concept. One fire can split to become multiple fires, and two fires may merge into one. // The noncount/count relation seems different from say 'flood': 'land of fire and flood' but 'Each year, fire causes over $2 billion worth of damage to homes' works while 'Each year, flood causes over $x worth of damage to homes' is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

On the same line of thought, and with all due respect to the original poster.

But it does seem correct to ask:

A. 'Do Friendly Fires account for a significant increase in the number deaths in Afghanistan ?

Yet,

B. 'Does Friendly Fire account for a significant increase in the number deaths in Afghanistan ?

I assume both statements to be correct. But in the situation I'm in presenting a statistical report with a number of tables in the report, one of which showing the breakdown of the number of deaths in Afghanistan for a period of time: Vehicle Crashes, Electrocutions, Heatstroke, Friendly Fire, and Suicides on Duty.

Though B is the correct form to use as it is referring to my table. But I would still assume A to be correct still considering the question is referring to what the statistics for Friendly Fire represents which is not a number but the cause, result, and repercussion by the action of Friendly Fire (and maybe even what that number amounts to or what is it all about?). All good and valid.

Nothing changes in the rules of pluralization whether it's cancer or deaths in Afghanistan right? No matter what, the plural of 'fish' is still 'fish', being an exception right ?

Marc

— I am not that proficient in English, French being my primary language. Being conscious of my English, I'm always looking for concurrence in these situations such as this.

Comment: 'Friendly fire' is a compound noun (see [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/friendly%20fire)) and, unlike one of the words from which it obviously derives, never used in count usages. 'Friendly Fires account for a significant increase in the number of casualties' is like saying 'Angers were palpable in the conference room where the heads of state were gathered.'

Comment: I agree with @EdwinAshworth. Your sentence A is not something I would accept as grammatical, and marks you as a non-native speaker.